# Почему при вводе символа, не принадлежащему множествам, не заходит в if?

Tags: c++, функции, множества

Функция ниже должна редактировать строку удаляя из неё лишние символы если этот символ не пробел, не латинская буква, или не цифра. Но почему-то даже если ввести русскую букву, или любой другой символ не из допустимого множества, то в этот if не заходит.

```
string editing(string sentence)
{
    int i;
    i = 1;
    while (i <= sentence.length())
    {
        if (!('0' <= sentence[i] <= '9' || 'A' <= sentence[i] <='Z' || 'a' <= sentence[i] <= 'z' || sentence[i] == ' '))
        {
            sentence.erase(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return sentence;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот это, например

```
'0' <= sentence[i] <= '9'
```

компилятор рассматривает как

```
('0' <= sentence[i]) <= '9'
```

так что больше `sentence[i]` чем `0` или меньше - мы все равно получим что-то (`true` или `false`), меньшее, чем `9` - так что весь результат получается `true`.

Еще учтите, что массивы и иже с ними ведут счет элементов с 0, так что элемент

```
sentence[sentence.length()]
```

**не существует**. Выход за границы элемента, UB...

Comment: Идиотское (нет) сравнение всплывает из математики. Там это абсолютно корректная запись условия принадлежности диапазону. Увы ,по всей видимости преподаватели забывают объяснить ученикам, что подавляющее большинство языков не поддерживает математическую нотацию

Comment: Сравнение возникает не только из математики, но ещё и из питона, где такая запись вполне валидна

Comment: если sentence - std::string, то `sentence[sentence.length()]` не является UB

Comment: @KoVadim Насколько я помню, до С++11 являлось.

Comment: да, но там были ограничения.